# Capacitive sensing vs inductive sensing Comparison

Tags: capacitor, inductor

Apart from this technology being implemented with 2 different passive components, what are the major difference between the 2?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are literally whole books (yes, plural) written on the topic, especially for capacitive sensing (which is somewhat more versatile)

In short you are using transducers which vary their capacitance/inductance depending on *what* you want to measure/detect.

For capacitors, the capacitance formula says that capacitance (for simple plates!) depends on:

- Area of the facing plate
- Distance of the plates
- Dielectric

plus disturbance caused by other near electric fields/capacitors (i.e. fingers for touch sensing, where the finger is more or less a capacitance to ground)

So you could for example make a position sensor sliding one plate over another, as in cheap calipers: that varies the surface; or attach a plate to a diaphragm to measure pressure: that varies the distance. Some liquid level sensors works by detecting the liquid as a variation of dielectric.

As for the circuitry you 'only' need to measure the capacitance so you could measure the reactance or using it as a timing element in an oscillator, for example.

Inductive sensing usually only senses the variations due to near metal masses: that's the iconic industrial proximity sensor. Also you can make a pseudo-touch that detect the minute deflection of a metal plate pressed by a finger.

Like for the capacitor you can measure the reactance or using the inductor as timing element (non exhaustive list!)

If you also add a metal/ferrite core and maybe another winding and obtain many cool transformer transducers like LVDT, synchros and sin/cos encoders. These usually work by applying an AC signal on one side and then comparing the phase/amplitude on the output. Very performant, very expensive, too.

As you see there are *a lot* of technologies based on both capacitive and inductive sensing.

Comment: Thanks for your input Lorenzo